# Diamond falls and got no tooltip of its own in chat mini profile

Tags: bug, chat, moderators, tooltips

See what happens to the Diamond when the user name is too long:

> [image]

In addition to falling into a new line, it doesn't have the "moderator" tooltip it got anywhere else over the network.

Tooltip should exist in my opinion, and the word next to the diamond should wrap as well so to not make it feel so lonely down there.

Comment: Still listening to music...huh? ;)

Comment: @Lix lol! No music for me actually, it does have tooltip showing the reputation. :D